# What is a base chess engine?

Tags: engines, software

For the asmFish 2017 11 05 there is one option as a base bmi2 and popcnt.  What does base mean?  Is it just a weaker version of the correct one or is it the fully capable engine
https://github.com/lantonov/asmFish/tree/executables/Windows

Answer (score 1):

The `base` version is for everybody, all Windows users. The `other` versions are built for specific hardwares, and should outperform the base version if you have the hardware.

Try the `bmi2` and `popcnt` versions, if they crash on you fall back to the base version.